# android - Get location in Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, maps

Hello I have read about this a lot and I don't figure out why I get null when retrieving my own location, I'm testing in Android Studio emulator and my own phone and I get the same null value.
Here is my entire code in progress:

```
public class mapaFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;
    private boolean mLocationPermissionGranted;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mCurrentLocation;
    private Location ultimaLocalizacion;
    private MapFragment fragment;
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    private Cliente cliente;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private CameraPosition mCameraPosition;
    private TextView textoError;
    private final LatLng mDefaultLocation = new LatLng(-33.8523341, 151.2106085);

    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 10000;
    private static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            cliente = getArguments().getParcelable("clienteSeleccionado");
        }
    }


    //Implementa este metodo que es al que se llama en las lineas anteriores si no tienes permisos
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        createLocationRequest();

        if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION && requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                LatLng latitudLongitud = new LatLng(ultimaLocalizacion.getLatitude(), ultimaLocalizacion.getLongitude());
                CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latitudLongitud, 16);
                mMap.setMapStyle(new MapStyleOptions(""));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latitudLongitud, 16));
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latitudLongitud).title("Usted está aquí"));
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(cliente.getLatitud(), cliente.getLongitud())).title(cliente.getNombre()));

            } else {

                getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textoErrorMapa).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mapView).setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
            return;
        }
        updateLocationUI();

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mapa, container, false);

    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        fragment = (MapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView);
        fragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;
        //
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            generarInstanciaClienteAPI();
        }


    }

    protected synchronized void generarInstanciaClienteAPI() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    private void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.create();
//
//    /*
//     * Sets the desired interval for active location updates. This interval is
//     * inexact. You may not receive updates at all if no location sources are available, or
//     * you may receive them slower than requested. You may also receive updates faster than
//     * requested if other applications are requesting location at a faster interval.
//     */
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
//
//    /*
//     * Sets the fastest rate for active location updates. This interval is exact, and your
//     * application will never receive updates faster than this value.
//     */
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
//
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        ultimaLocalizacion = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        int permissionCheckFINE = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        int permissionCheckCOARSE = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        if ((permissionCheckFINE == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) || (permissionCheckCOARSE == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)){
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        } else {
            createLocationRequest();

            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            LatLng latitudLongitud = new LatLng(ultimaLocalizacion.getLatitude(), ultimaLocalizacion.getLongitude());
            CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latitudLongitud, 16);
            mMap.setMapStyle(new MapStyleOptions(""));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latitudLongitud, 16));
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latitudLongitud).title("Usted está aquí"));
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(cliente.getLatitud(), cliente.getLongitud())).title(cliente.getNombre()));
        }
        updateLocationUI();
        //createLocationRequest();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
    /**
     * Updates the map's UI settings based on whether the user has granted location permission.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
    private void updateLocationUI() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        } else {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
            ultimaLocalizacion = null;
        }
    }



    private void getDeviceLocation() {
    /*
     * Request location permission, so that we can get the location of the
     * device. The result of the permission request is handled by a callback,
     * onRequestPermissionsResult.
     */
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

        }
    /*
     * Get the best and most recent location of the device, which may be null in rare
     * cases when a location is not available.
     * Also request regular updates about the device location.
     */
        if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
            mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                    mLocationRequest, this);


        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mCurrentLocation = location;
        updateMarkers();
    }
    private void updateMarkers() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            return;
        }else{
            LatLng prueba = new LatLng(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(),mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(prueba)
                    .title("Estás aquí"));

        }

        if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
            // Get the businesses and other points of interest located
            // nearest to the device's current location.
            @SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
            PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
                    .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);
            result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult( PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
                    for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
                        // Add a marker for each place near the device's current location, with an
                        // info window showing place information.
                        String attributions = (String) placeLikelihood.getPlace().getAttributions();
                        String snippet = (String) placeLikelihood.getPlace().getAddress();
                        if (attributions != null) {
                            snippet = snippet + "\n" + attributions;
                        }

                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(placeLikelihood.getPlace().getLatLng())
                                .title((String) placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName())
                                .snippet(snippet));
                    }
                    // Release the place likelihood buffer.
                    likelyPlaces.release();
                }
            });
        } else {
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(mDefaultLocation)
                    .title("Por defecto")
                    .snippet(""));
        }
    }
}
```

I have read about the lyfecicle and everything but I don't know what is wrong, hope somebody can help me.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment ?

Comment: Excuse me, it is already done, the problem is when I try to get my own location, the map itself works and shows coordinates properly.